# PHP echo MYSQL Value to URL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm attempting to carry the value of a cell to the end of my URL so that I delete the targeted row from a MYSQL table respectively. However, the value in `$row['waybill_ID']` does not carry as expected. What can I do to remedy this? I understand that this is slightly drawn out, but I am doing this a part of a 'are you sure' prompt.

```
<html>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;
</a>
<div class="overlay-content">
<h2 style="color: white">Are you sure you want to delete this record?</h2>
<h2 style="color: white">This record will no longer exist after 
deletion</h2>
<a id="deletePrompt" href="#" target="blank">Delete Record</a> 
</div>
</div>

<div class="midA">
    <div class='wrapper'>
        <button class="accordion">Unit(s) and Driver(s)</button>
        <div class="panel">
            <div class='buffer'>
        <?php

        //Unitboard Display
        $issue_ID = $_GET['idx'];
        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM unitboard WHERE issue_ID = '$issue_ID'") or die($msqli->error);
                    echo"
        <table border= 1px solid white>
        <tr>
            <th>Action</th>
            <th>Waybill_ID</th>
            <th>Driver</th>
            <th>Unit Type</th>
            <th>Move Type</th>
            <th>Route ID</th>
            <th>Tractor Number</th>
            <th>Trailer Number</th>
            <th>Waybill Status</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>";?><?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
        <td>
            <a href="#" onclick="window.open( 'editUnitBoard.php?idx=<?php echo $row['waybill_ID'] ?>', 'name', 'location=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no' )">edit</a>      
            <a href="#" onclick="openNav()">delete</a>
        </td>
         <?php echo"
            <td>{$row['waybill_ID']}</td>
            <td>{$row['driver']}</td>
            <td>{$row['unitType']}</td>
            <td>{$row['moveType']}</td>
            <td>{$row['location_ID']}</td>
            <td>{$row['tractorNum']}</td>
            <td>{$row['trailerNum']}</td>
            <td>{$row['waybillStatus']}</td>
        </tr>"; 
        }
        echo'<table></table>';

        ?>

            <button style="margin-top: 15px; float: right" class='button' type="button" a href="#" onclick="window.open( 'formNewUnit.php?idx=<?php echo $_GET['idx'] ?>', 'name', 'location=no,scrollbars=yes,status=no,toolbar=no,resizable=no' )">Create New Unit</button>

            <a href="viewRun.php?idx=<?php echo $_GET['idx'] ?>" target="_blank">view</a>

            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
document.getElementById("deletePrompt").href="editUnitBoard.php?idx=<?php 
echo $row['waybill_ID']; ?>"; 
return false;
}

function closeNav() {
document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

The result is   editUnitBoard.php?idx=   but    I need something link editUnitBoard.php?id=1234    for example

Comment: echo $row['waybill_ID']; perhaps? missing the ; off the end of the php line.

Comment: There is nothing in the code you've shown us to populate $row

Comment: From where you are fetching this Value `$row['waybill_ID']`. ? Are you fetching it from Database ?  Paste that PHP Code.

Comment: In addition, there is no element with id 'deleteFunc' in your html.If you are running this code alone, without populating the php variable $row, you will have establish a database connection and get the desired record.

Comment: Apologies- I've added the full code for reference now

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps, select the column, enter the ID and use echo $value[0]['*column name*'];

Its not SQL Injection proof, I think.

```
        $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        $query = mysqli_query($this->db_connection,"SELECT value FROM settings WHERE id='1'");
        $value = mysqli_fetch_all($query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: Sorry, luuktap- I wasn't clear on the question. I've included the full code above for reference now.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is what I've been looking for. Thank you all for your time!

```
        $testro = $row['driver'];
        $mysqli2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'disolDemo');
        $query2 = " SELECT
            unitboard.driver,
            unitboard.officeLocation,
            trackingboard.issue_ID,
            unitboard.waybill_ID,
            unitboard.arrivalDateTimeDest,
            unitboard.unitType,
            unitboard.totalMiles,
            unitboard.waybillStatus,
            unitboard.moveType,
            trackingboard.customer

        FROM trackingboard INNER JOIN unitboard ON trackingboard.issue_ID = unitboard.issue_ID WHERE driver = '$testro'";
```